# Somar Count() no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, query

Tenho essa query que me retorna a quantidade de datas iguais:

```
SELECT `Data`, COUNT(`Data`) AS 'Quantidade' FROM sua_tabela GROUP BY `Data`;
```

> ```
> | Data         |
> | 2016-06-09   |
> | 2016-06-09   |
> | 2016-06-09   |
> | 2016-06-08   |
> | 2016-06-08   |
> | 2016-06-05   |
> | 2016-06-01   |
> ```

Retorna assim:

> ```
> | Data       | Quantidade |
> | 2016-06-09 |     3      |
> | 2016-06-08 |     2      |
> | 2016-06-05 |     1      |
> | 2016-06-01 |     1      |
> ```

Gostaria então de somar a Quantidade retornada referente a este mês

Tentei desta forma:

```
SELECT Data_reg, SUM(COUNT(Data_reg)) AS 'Soma_total'
FROM Monit 
WHERE Data_reg like ('2016-06%')
GROUP BY `Data_reg`;
```

Porém retornou o seguinte erro:

> Erro SQL (1111): Invalid use of group function

Comment: voce quer contar somente as datas iguais, ou somente contar ?

Comment: Na minha tabela possui varias outras datas, mas gostaria de somar só o mês que filtrei no exemplo

Comment: Tá retornando o mesmo erro

Comment: perdão, tirei a data no lugar errado: `SELECT SUM(COUNT(Data_reg)) AS 'Soma_total' FROM Monit WHERE Data_reg like ('2016-06%') group by data_reg;`

Comment: O mesmo erro persiste :(

Comment: `SELECT   sum(count(data)) qt
  FROM   (SELECT   '03/01/2018' data FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL
          SELECT   '01/01/2018' data FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL
          SELECT   '01/01/2018' data FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL
          SELECT   '02/01/2018' data FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL
          SELECT   '02/01/2018' data FROM DUAL)
  
  GROUP BY data` veja esse código que fiz aqui, que é exatamente igual ao seu, executa normalmente, tem certeza que o erro que da é de `group by`? (não vai executar no mysql, pois a tabela virtual criada nele faz parte de funcoes do oracle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não precisa somar os `COUNT`. Basta fazer um `COUNT` normal que irá retornar o total de registros do `LIKE`:

```
SELECT Data_reg, COUNT(Data_reg) AS Soma_total FROM Monit WHERE Data_reg like '2016-06%'
```

No seu caso, a query acima irá retornar `7`, que é exatamente a soma dos valores em "Quantidade" da sua query inicial (3 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 7):

```
| Data       | Quantidade |
| 2016-06-09 |     3      |
| 2016-06-08 |     2      |
| 2016-06-05 |     1      |
| 2016-06-01 |     1      |
```